# A curry function that executes another function n times

Tags: sml

I'm solving an old exam to practice SML. One task I found interesting was: Write a function `repeat` that executes another function with the signature 'a -> 'a.

I assumed the requested function is a curry function and used the `o`-Operator:

```
fun repeat (1, f: 'a->'a) = f
|   repeat (n, f: 'a->'a) = f o repeat (n-1, f);
```

However, the `o` operator was not formally introduced in out course, and I wonder how I could write this without it?

Comment: (note the down vote was not me). You need not use the `o` operator (although that could make sense… as much as abusing this operator), and anyway, not that way. You rather have to recurse using the previous result from `f`. Note the question's text says “execute another function”, not “return a function” and you're attempting to return a function here. Is this for an assignment?

Comment: @Hibou57 This question is from an old exam I'm working on to practice, as I'll take an exam myself next Wednesday. --- I figured a curry function was more challenging to write than the regular version, so I tried, but could not solve it without the `o `. Could you elaborate how you would solve it?

Comment: As for a non curry version, I guess it would be something like `fun repeat (x, f:'a->'a, 0) = x | repeat (x, f, n) = repeat (f(x), f, n-1)`.

Comment: yes (for the version posted in comment). I will post an answer with explanation, later.

Comment: @Downvoters: Please let me know what is wrong with the question. I honestly don't see what is wrong with it.

Comment: (Btw, today's exam went great, and I could solve all SML questions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the less verbose, but in some way, the most explicit, then after, the less verbose, with explanations.

A curried function is a function getting a single argument. If an expression has more arguments, then there are as many nested functions. The first outer level function gets an argument, and is made of an inner level function which may it‑self be made of an inner function, and so on. Any of this inner level function may be returned, not just the innermost, as explained later (this is a kind of “partial evaluation”). An inner function is “specialized” with the arguments (formally, the arguments are bound in a closure) of the outer functions.

We know there are at least a function argument `f` and integer argument `counter`. There needs to be an argument `seed` also, to invoke the function `f` the first time.

The order of nesting may be arbitrary or specified. If not specified, I personally prefer to put the least varying arguments on the outer‑scope and the most varying in the inner‑scope. Here, I would say it is, from least to most varying: `f`, `counter` `seed`.

This is already enough to suggest the beginning of a template:

```
val repeat: ('a -> 'a) -> int -> 'a -> 'a =
   fn f: 'a -> 'a =>
      fn count: int =>
         fn seed: 'a =>
            …
```

We already implemented the `('a -> 'a) -> int -> 'a` part of the signature. Remains the last `-> 'a` which means an `'a` is to be returned, and it will be evaluated by an inner loop.

A loop may be something of this form (in pseudo‑code):

```
val rec loop = fn i =>
   if condition-to-stop
      then return-something-or-`()`
   else loop (i + 1) or (i - 1)
```

If the loop is to compute something, it will need an extra argument acting as an accumulator, and will return that accumulator as its final result.

Implementing the loop and putting it inside the curried function template above, we get:

```
val repeat: ('a -> 'a) -> int -> 'a -> 'a =
   fn f: 'a -> 'a =>
      fn count: int =>
         fn seed: 'a =>
            let
               val rec loop = fn (counter, x) =>
                  if counter <= 0 then x
                  else loop (counter - 1, f x)
            in
               loop (count, seed)
            end
```

Do you understand the `let … in … end` construct here?

Note the guard on `counter` may use a pattern as you did, but as SML's integer may be negative (there is no strict natural in SML), that's safer to catch this case too, thus the `if … then … else` instead of a pattern matching. Mileage may vary on that point, but that's not the question's focus.

The same as above, using `fun` instead of `val rec`:

```
fun repeat (f: 'a -> 'a) (count: int) (seed: 'a): 'a =
   let
      fun loop (counter, x) =
         if counter <= 0 then x
         else loop (counter - 1, f x)
   in
      loop (count, seed)
   end
```

Note for `repeat` the arguments are not separated by a `,` (neither a `*`). This is the way to write a curried function using `fun` (on the contrary, `loop` is not curried). Compare it with the prior `val` version of the same function. If no type is specified and only names, the parenthesis can be omitted.

A test function to be used as the `f` argument:

```
val appendAnX = fn s: string => s ^ "x"
```

The test:

```
val () = print (repeat appendAnX 5 "Blah:")
```

Curried function are more abstract than function getting a tuple (which is formally a single argument, thus makes a curried function too, but that's another story and a bit cheating), as the outer function(s) may be partially applied:

This is a partial application, leaving the last argument, `seed`, unbound:

```
val repeatAppendAnXThreeTimes = repeat appendAnX 3
```

Then this function may be applied specifiying only this `seed`:

```
val () = print (repeatAppendAnXThreeTimes "Blah:")
```

Similarly, both `counter` and `seed` may be left free:

```
val repeatAppendAnX = repeat appendAnX
val () = print (repeatAppendAnX 4 "Blah:")
```

Another way of defining `repeatAppendAnXThreeTimes`. Compare it to its other definition above:

```
val repeatAppendAnXThreeTimes = repeatAppendAnX 3
val () = print (repeatAppendAnXThreeTimes "Blah:")
```

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough answer. I will need to review it carefully until I completely understand it. Given your structured way, I'm not surprised that I could not find a solution, there is some magic happening here!

Comment: @mafu, that's not magic, that's just closures. This is an important property of the lambda calculus. Think of it as symbol binding. It's also important to understand a function may return a function, as in the lambda‑calculus, functions are expressions among other expressions.